# Working with Sublime Text on local server

Tags: database-connection, localhost, sublimetext, remote-server

Sublime Text is good native text editor for web developers and other programmers. Using ftp feature is not user friendly, so my question is second:

> **What is the best practices to work locally with sublime text editor?**

Main problem is:

- After do some changes on localhost(database is on localhost, not on
  remote server) i want see immediately result on remote server.

Please, give me some practical info.

Answer (score 2):

For **Windows** a good tool which allows automated sync(including deletes) with remote and also allows to add exclusion rules is [**WinScp**](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php)

for **Mac** the same can be done using [**Yummy FTP Watcher**](http://www.yummysoftware.com/Product-Information-Watcher/)

NetBeans IDE is available on both mac and windows and 8.0.2 version has perfect upload on save function which also updates remove on file add and delete.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Sublime SFTP](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp) package by wbond, the creator of [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control). It works for FTP, SFTP, and FTPS connections, allows syncing of files/folders (in both directions), and is pretty much invaluable for this kind of work. It costs US$16, but is definitely worth it.

Alternatively, if you're on a Mac, check out [Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/). It allows you to map SSH/FTP shares as a local volume, so you can use any program, not just Sublime. It's US$34, but very much worth it.

For other operating systems, google "[FUSE](https://www.google.com/?q=fuse+your+favorite+OS)" (file system in user space). Many Linux distros have packages available for various solutions, and there are versions for Windows as well. They essentially do the same thing as Transmit in allowing you to map a network resource to a local drive/volume.

Comment: you can use `Sublime SFTP` without a license, but you will see annoying popups every now and then.